# Combine Java 8 Optionals with conditional AND

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type, logical-operators

My Problem is I have two or more Optionals wrapping different types.
I want to perform an operation which only can be performed if all optionals are not empty.

Currently Im doing it this way:

```
    Optional<PatientCase> caseOptional = patientCaseRepository.findOneById(caseId);
    Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findOneById(caseId);

    if(userOptional.isPresent() && caseOptional.isPresent()) {
        caseOptional.get().getProcess().setDesigner(userOptional.get());
    }
```

In my opinion the if condition does not feel right.
I know it is possible to chain Optionals using orElse.
But in my case I don't want a logical Else.
Is there a way to create and AND Operator in order to combine two or more Optionals
similar to this PSEUDO code ?

```
caseOptional.and.userOptional.ifPresent((theCase,user) -> //Perform Stuff);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a logical AND operation, but there is no (simple) way to turn it into a two-value `Optional`, in other words, this (again) suffers from the absence of pair or tuple types. E.g.

```
caseOptional.flatMap(theCase -> userOptional
        .map(user -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(theCase, user)))
    .ifPresent(e -> e.getKey().getProcess().setDesigner(e.getValue()));
```

which uses `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` as stand-in for the absent tuple type.

An alternative would be be using a singleton map as pair:

```
caseOptional.flatMap(theCase -> userOptional
        .map(user -> Collections.singletonMap(theCase, user)))
    .ifPresent(m -> m.forEach((c, u) -> c.getProcess().setDesigner(u)));
```

But in this specific case, you may use the simpler

```
caseOptional.map(PatientCase::getProcess)
            .ifPresent(p -> userOptional.ifPresent(p::setDesigner));
```

or

```
caseOptional.ifPresent(c -> userOptional.ifPresent(u -> c.getProcess().setDesigner(u)));
```

instead.

Comment: The last form looks a lot like a monad, maybe it can be formalized as one :)

Comment: Thx for the given examples/suggestions. The first two only seem to work for two, and not more than two optionals. I think more can be achieved using a custom object which holds the optionals. But this is a bigger overhead. The last two suggestions show that it is possible to chain several optionals using the ifPresent in a nested way. So it is a solution for the given problem, but unfortunately the readability of the code decreases with every added optional.I will still wait a little if someone finds another method with better readability, otherwise I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 8):

There is no direct way.

Stram `allMatch` will work like ifPresent for many optionals:

```
Stream.of(optional1, optional2, ...).allMatch(Optional::isPresent)
```

Comment: Using this technique, I can validate that all optionals are present. But It is not possible to chain further function calls. This step must again be controlled using an if clause and later I have to unwrap these optionals. But the coding overhead is a little smaller when validating more than two optionals so its in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question itself has been answered but, in general, all the states of the combination of optional1 (call it '`A`') and optional2 (call it '`B`') can be obtained by chaining `map()` and `orElse()` or similar. The key to this sort of question is to remember that the function that is applied inside the `Optional.map()` is only applied to a 'real' value.

```
A.map(a->B.map(b->"A&&B").
           orElse("A&&!B")).
  orElse(B.map(b->"!A&&B").
           orElse("!A&&!B"));
```

So `map()` handles the case when the Optional is not empty and `orElse()` handles the case when the Optional is empty.